# What is Difference between Runnable in a ThreadPool vs Runnable inside a Thread and in a ThreadPool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool

What is the difference on this? Please refer to option 1 and option2. Because I'm having trouble because it's like they are the same. They run correctly

[Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhcMN.png)

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        Thread callLogsThread = new Thread(new CallLogsRunnable());
        Thread contactsThread = new Thread(new ContactsRunnable());

        /*option 1**/
        executor.submit(new ContactsRunnable());
        executor.submit(new CallLogsRunnable());

        /*option 2**/
        executor.submit(contactsThread);
        executor.submit(callLogsThread);

        /*option 3**/
        contactsThread.start();
        contactsThread.join();
        callLogsThread.start();
        callLogsThread.join();

        executor.shutdown();
```

**UPDATE :** I added option 3. What is difference now between Option 1 and Option 3. Cause I understand that option 2 is a crap. thank you

Comment: `Thread implements Runnable`, which is generally considered to have been a mistake. Using `Thread#run()`, as your executor does here, is no different from calling the runnable directly except for having extra objects in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the functionality / behavioral perspective, there is no difference.  Calling `run()` on a `Thread` object will call the `Runnable` that was passed as a constructor argument; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--) for `Thread::run()`.

From the efficiency perspective, the second option creates unnecessary `Thread` objects.  This reduces performance, increases memory utilization and increases GC load.

(The efficiency impact will be small, but since the `Thread` objects don't achieve anything .... just don't do it.)

From a readability / mantainability perspective, the second option will cause a *"what the heck"* reaction from any experience Java programmer reading your code.  You don't want that.  It wastes peoples' time to have to work out what "odd" code is doing.

---

You added a 3rd option where you `start()` threads instead of using existing threads in a thread pool.

It is worse than both option 1 and 2.  Instead of using a thread pool, you now start a new thread for each task.  That is *much less efficient*.  The overheads of a thread starting and then exiting are measured in thousands of clock cycles ...

Comment: thank you very much sir for a very informative answer. Hope I can upvote. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says Option 2) only works because `Thread` implements `Runnable`, where the `run` method is the action that the thread is supposed to perform.

If you pass the `Thread` to the executor it will call the `Thread`s `run()` method - but there will be no gain from the actual `Thread` itself. So Option 2) is wrong.

If you want to start the `Runnable` in a thread directly use `callLogsThread.start()` - and then don't forget to `join()` it when the thread has finished.

Comment: /*option 2**/
        contactsThread.start();
        contactsThread.join();
        callLogsThread.start();
        callLogsThread.join();

what if  do this sir? what is the difference with this between option 1?